# Extract django multi-select form choice

Tags: javascript, django

I want to reload part of my page upon form submit.
To do this i´d like to extract the selected fields from a Django multiselectfield.
Now I´m kinda stuck because Django renders the form like this:

[image]

Instead of select-Tags.
How can i extract which choices have been selected?
Or is there any way to return new information when the form has been selected without leaving the page?

Answer (score 0):

You get the value in exactly the same way as for any other form field: via `form.cleaned_data`. In this case, `form.cleaned_data['Messwerte']`.

Comment: I should have made my question clearer: I want to extract the values directly in the html because once the form is submitted i cant reload only a part of my page